# header including error when using C++ file in Swift project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, swift5

I am using C++ files in swift project, but in swift project, we can't use C++ file directly and should use objective-c file.
So I created **IFCEngineLib.h** and **IFCEngineLib.m** file for using **IFCFileParser.h** and **IFCFileParser.cpp**.
And in IFCEngineLib.mm, I include IFCFileParser.h file as following:

```
#import "IFCEngineLib.h"

#include "IFCFileParser.h"

CIFCFileParser *g_pModel = NULL;

@implementation IFCEngineLib
....
@end
```

But when I build project, I got following errors:

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'PKPushRegistryDelegate'
```

I used PKPushRegistryDelegate in AppDelegate.swift and also import PushKit in there as following:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//
import UIKit
import CoreData    
import UserNotifications    
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {
...
}
```

How can I fix this error? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where does the error appear?

Comment: That error appear in bridging header file

Comment: Can we see the header file and which line causes the error?

Comment: In fact, this is private project, so I can't show you project. but I can show you screenshot.

Comment: If you want help, provide details.  I'm not interested in guessing.

Comment: which header file do you want to see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215954/discussion-between-zhengyu-and-phillip-mills).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve this problem.
I have to import the **all header files** of **objective-C libraries** using in the application in IFCEngineLib.m.
I used PushKit in application, so I have to import **`<PushKit/PushKit.h>`** in IFCEngineLib.m.
So IFCEngineLib.m file looks like as following:

```
#import "IFCEngineLib.h"
#import <PushKit/PushKit.h>

#include "IFCFileParser.h"

CIFCFileParser *g_pModel = NULL;

@implementation IFCEngineLib
....
@end
```

if you use audioplayer, then you have to import **#import `<AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>`**. That's all.